# Trying to replicate AVL Balance algorithm (as depicted in wikipedia)

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Currently I'm doing some practice learning/coding about AVL Trees and RB Trees. After looking at the balance algorithm as depicted on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), I tried my best to replicate it in C#, but I get mixed results. If I add (2,1,0,-1), it balances correctly. If I insert -2, it does balance out, however 0 becomes the root, and I get -2 & -1 on the left side & 1 & 2 on the right side. If done correctly, I should get 1 is still the root, and on the left I have -1 which has -2 as the left child and 0 as the right child. I've double checked my rotations and they are implemented as they should be.

```
    public void Add(int data)
    {
        Node newItem = new Node(data);
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = newItem;
        }
        else
        {
            RecursiveInsert(root, newItem);

        }
        n++;
        Balance_Tree(root);//Balance_Tree is called HERE
    }
    private void RecursiveInsert(Node current, Node n)
    {
        if (n.data < current.data)
        {
            if (current.left == null)
            {
                current.left = n;
            }
            else { RecursiveInsert(current.left, n); }
        }
        if (n.data > current.data)
        {
            if (current.right == null)
            {
                current.right = n;
            }
            else { RecursiveInsert(current.right, n); }
        }
    }
private void Balance_Tree(Node current)
    {
        Node P;
        if (Balance_Factor(current) == 2)//left column
        {
            P = current.left;
            if (Balance_Factor(P) == -1)
            {
                root = RotateLeftRight(P);//left right case
            }
            else
            {
                root = RotateLeftLeft(current);//left left case
            }
        }
        if (Balance_Factor(current.left) == -2)//right column
        {
            P = current.right;
            if (Balance_Factor(P) == 1)
            {
                root = RotateRightLeft(P);//right left case
            }
            else
            {
               root = RotateLeftLeft(current);//right right case
            }
        }
    }
    private int Balance_Factor(Node current)
    {
        int left_h = GetLeftHeight(current);
        int right_h = GetRightHeight(current);
        int b_factor = left_h - right_h;
        return b_factor;
    }
    private int GetLeftHeight(Node current)
    {
        int l_h = 0;
        while (current != null)
        {
            current = current.left;
            l_h++;
        }
        return l_h;
    }
    private int GetRightHeight(Node current)
    {
        int r_h = 0;
        while (current != null)
        {
            current = current.right;
            r_h++;
        }
        return r_h;
    }
    private Node RotateLeftLeft(Node Parent)
    {
        Node pivot = Parent.left;
        Parent.left = pivot.right;
        pivot.right = Parent;
        return pivot;
    }
    private Node RotateRightRight(Node Parent)
    {
        Node pivot = Parent.right;
        Parent.right = pivot.left;
        pivot.left = Parent;
        return pivot;
    }
```

Comment: could you post the code that `Balance_Tree` is called? without that we can only guess the behavior, but not trace the behavior.

Comment: If you have {0, {-1, -2}, {1, 2}} its balanced, {1, {-1, {-2}}, {0, {2}}} isn't balanced.

Comment: like I mentioned in my answer, I need you to answer a question for me: how do you update your balance factor? Besides, please post your `RecursiveInsert` function as well.

Comment: Well I've updated my sample code posted with the RecursiveInsert function and the Balance_Factor function, so that you can see how I update the balance factor.